# How to trigger warnings on an unplugged aural warning unit?

Tags: avionics, aircraft-maintenance

I got an old [80-0557-11](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjAw/z/jdMAAOSw32lYpK7F/$_57.JPG) Rev A manufactured by Grimmes from an EMB-120 Brasilia, and I was wondering how to make it speak.

I powered the component with a 28VDC power supply. It only said "Aural unit Ok" while I was expecting a lot of warnings, due the lack of connected sensors.

Checking an old wiring manual, I realized that most of the sensor inputs have a single connection, not a "HI/LO (+/-)" lines.

Does someone have some idea about how make it play alarms?

Thank you in advance for anyone who can explain me the logic of the system. Please, keep in mind that I'm just a enthusiast trying to better understand how this system works.

Comment: I suspect that "Aural Unit OK" is just an internal self-test. In order for it to "speak what she knows", it may have to be hooked into real (or simulated) signals. Without having a wiring diagram or information on how this unit hooks up and communicates, it will be a very difficult question to answer. While not off-topic because it requires product-specific information, this knowledge is highly specialized and it may be unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank You for your comment Ron, i understand that's highly speciacialized knowledge, but maybe it's not a mistery like we expect. That's the reason why i brought this question to this room! :)

Comment: Are you sure it _should_ say something when powered on but without the various sensors? It may be working exactly as designed. Sounds like you've got (at least some of) the manuals, so that, mostly likely, makes you more expert on this than any of us. (Unless, of course, an A&P happens to wander by who knows this particular unit...)

Comment: This [Ops Manual](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/OPSMANS611-WARNINGSYSTEMS.pdf) may be of help.  The aural unit can pass-through audio from devices such as the TAWS or TCAS. Most of the other alerts are internally stored audio files that are triggered by the external systems. The single wire connections are discretes.  They may be OPEN/GROUND (try grounding to see if it triggers) or 28V/OPEN (applying 28V will trigger).

Comment: @Gerry The Ops Manual tip was great. I was analyzing just the aircraft maintenance manual. I'll try to grounding and if it doesn't work i'll look for more info if it's safe to apply 28V on this lines. Thank you Gerry! :)

Comment: I used to fly this plane, "aural unit ok" is indeed what it says when you first power up and it completes it's self test.  You will probably need to hook up an alarm cancel button, IIRC at first power up a lot of the warning circuits are lit up but it doesn't say anything until you cancel an alarm, the trigger goes away, then comes back.  Also, a lot of the warnings are inhibited with weight on wheels so you may have to simulate that signal also. Good luck, I want to hear some recordings when you figure it out!

Comment: Thank You Guys! Because you all i accomplished to make it work! :) @nexus_2006 please, send me your email by private message, i'll be glad to share with you!

Comment: @drmwndr Stack Exchange doesn't have private messaging, but if you look at my profile you can see my github name nexus2006 and in my profile there is a public email, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question based on tips posted on comments:

As @Gerry suggested on comments, they are OPEN/GROUND, if i ground any of sensor cables it'll trigger the alarms. Those lines are 5V, and i think that most of sensors are just simple switches, except for the Fire Alarms, that i  couldn't trigger and has 6.8V over its line.

For now i got my AWU speaking.

Thank everybody who commented with their suggestions. Those were very very very useful,  you guys are awesome!

Comment: The fire signals come from something called a 'fire loop', which is basically a wire-shaped thermistor wrapped around the engine/apu.  Maybe researching that will lead you to a solution.  Its amazing you didn't fry your box experimenting with it, good work!